# Auto select an option from dropdown using href

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to have a dropdown menu auto select an option based on the href acquired from a button pressed on a previous page, which is stored in the address bar. I tried looking up this issue but I cannot seem to find anything regarding it, so I am left to assume I am wording this wrong, or it is just not possible.

Here is my code from index.html

```html
<div class="logo-row">
   <img src="./assets/img.png" onclick="function();" class="logo"/>
   <a href="./page1.html#sprites"><img src="./assets/sprites_placeholder.png" class="button p1"/></a>
   <a href="./page1.html#models"><img src="./assets/models_placeholder.png" class="button p1"/></a>
   <a href="./page1.html#textures"><img src="./assets/textures_placeholder.png" class="button p1"/></a>
   <a href="./page1.html#sounds"><img src="./assets/sounds_placeholder.png" class="button p1"/></a>
</div>
```

And here is the code from page1.html

```html
<div class="custom-select">
   <label class="resource">Resource:</label>
   <select id="selectBox" onchange="changeResource();">
      <option value="1" id="sprites">Sprites</option>
      <option value="2" id="models">Models</option>
      <option value="3" id="textures">Textures</option>
      <option value="4" id="sounds">Sounds</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

I'm not entirely sure this portrays what I'm trying to achieve, but when I test this with just pure text, it loads fine.

Comment: What JavaScript did you try?

Comment: @j08691 the JS that was used didn't have any exact attachment to the issue, I was mainly using it to switch header colours to ensure it was working, and storing the select box's selected index to compare a switch case for the selection. I should have removed the functions from the snippets to not mix up the confusion. I can also remove the javascript tag as well if needed.


If this solution can be solved via Javascript, I would be able to try it through the existing function used for the previously mentioned header colour switch case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the hash id from url and then set selected element from dropdown using javascript

```
<script>
var hash = location.hash.substr(1);
document.querySelector('option[id="'+hash+'"]').setAttribute('selected', true);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick response! Did exactly what I needed.